# Pythonshell.parser error using npm python-shell

Tags: python, node.js, parsing, tensorflow

I just want to communicate my python script with node js. I searched on google and find npm python-shell by which I can communicate.

But this error comes:

Error: Using TensorFlow backend.

```
    at PythonShell.parseError (C:\Users\rizwa\OneDrive\TalentHome-WebPanel\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:190:17)
    at terminateIfNeeded (C:\Users\rizwa\OneDrive\TalentHome-WebPanel\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:98:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rizwa\OneDrive\TalentHome-WebPanel\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:88:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
```

Python script:

```
      import numpy as np
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      import pandas as pd

      # Importing the dataset
      dataset = pd.read_csv('./python/Dummy-Dataset.csv')
      X = dataset.iloc[:, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,16]].values
      y = dataset.iloc[:, 17].values
      '''dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
      X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
      y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values'''
      # Encoding categorical data
      from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
      '''labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
      labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 2])'''
      labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
      labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 4])
      labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 6] = labelencoder_X_5.fit_transform(X[:, 6])
      labelencoder_X_6 = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 7] = labelencoder_X_6.fit_transform(X[:, 7])
      labelencoder_X_9 = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 10] = labelencoder_X_9.fit_transform(X[:, 10])
      labelencoder_X_11 = LabelEncoder()
      X[:, 12] = labelencoder_X_11.fit_transform(X[:, 12])
      onehotencoder_X = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
      X = onehotencoder_X.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      onehotencoder_X_1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [4])
      X = onehotencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      onehotencoder_X_2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [6]) 
      X = onehotencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      onehotencoder_X_3 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [7])
      X = onehotencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      onehotencoder_X_4 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [10])
      X = onehotencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      onehotencoder_X_5 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [12])
      X = onehotencoder_X_5.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      '''onehotencoder_X_5 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
      X = onehotencoder_X_5.fit_transform(X).toarray()'''
      X = X[:, 1:]

      # Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
      from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.05, 
      random_state = 0)

      # Feature Scaling
      from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      sc = StandardScaler()
      X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
      X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

      # Part 2 - Now let's make the ANN!
      # Just disables the warning, doesn't enable AVX/FMA
      import os
      os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
      # Importing the Keras libraries and packages
      import keras as keras
      from keras.models import Sequential
      from keras.layers import Dense

      # Initialising the ANN
      classifier = Sequential()

      # Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
      classifier.add(Dense(units = 16, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 
      'relu', input_dim = 32))

      # Adding the second hidden layer
      classifier.add(Dense(units = 16, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 
      'relu'))

      # Adding the output layer
      classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 
      'sigmoid'))

      # Compiling the ANN
      classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = 
      ['accuracy'])

      # Fitting the ANN to the Training set
      classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

      # Part 3 - Making predictions and evaluating the model

      # Predicting the Test set results
      y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
      y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

      # Making the Confusion Matrix
      from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
      cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Node.js:

```
     PythonShell.run('./python/ann.py', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('finished');
    });
```

An error comes just after importing tensorflow in a python script.

Comment: Enter code as text, properly formatted, and not pictures

Comment: Question updated!
Code with text without pictures.